# How to partially add a char-array to vector<char>

Tags: c++, vector, char, winsock

What is the best way to do this:

```
vector<char> content;
char MESSAGE[1024];
SUCCESSFUL = recv(sock_CONNECTION, MESSAGE, 1024, NULL);
for (int i = 0; i < SUCCESSFUL; i++)
    content.push_back(MESSAGE[i]);
```

I just found something like:

```
content.get_allocator = MESSAGE;
```

It doesn't have any errors, but I don't know how to cut `MESSAGE` from 0 to `SUCCESSFUL`.

Comment: note: `content.get_allocator = MESSAGE;` shouldn't compile, additionally, the [`get_allocator`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/get_allocator/) function returns the default allocator associated with the 2nd template parameter of the `vector` template (in your case, it's `allocator<char>`).

Comment: If you really want to avoid unnecessary copying, you should be able to use a 'content' vector filled with e.g. zeros (as many as necessary to accomodate all messages) and just feed a pointer with offset into 'content' directly to recv. Offset is location of next unused char.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
content.insert(content.end(), MESSAGE, MESSAGE+SUCCESSFUL);
```

Of course, don't forget to check if `recv()` failed, and returned `-1`, before you do this.